# BitBucket Webhook - Unable to connect to Jenkins URL

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am trying to create a webhook in BitBucket to trigger a build in Jenkins, but when I enter my Jenkins URL, and I test the connection, I get the error "Unable to connect to the URL specified, check the host and port are correct." I am using the URL http://localhost:8080/bitbucket-hook/ (with the last back slash included) and I can confirm that in Jenkins, my "Jenkins URL" is set to http://localhost:8080/. In Jenkins, I have installed the plugin "BitBucket Server Integration", and  under Configure System -> Bitbucket Server Integration, I have connected to the Bitbucket server (and when I test the connection, it says "Jenkins can connect with the Bitbucket Server", so I am pretty sure Jenkins is configured correctly). I don't have credentials set up in Jenkins for the Bitbucket Server configuration, is this necessary even though when I test the connection, it seems to be able to connect? Is my url for the BitBucket webhook correct?? Is there anything else you can think of that I might not have configured correctly so when I test the connection on BitBucket, it will connect properly?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran through a similar setup, to answer to your questions:

1. yes, I think you will have to use credentials of a user having admin permissions on the repository upon which you want to create the webhook.
2. Read below, anyway the Webhook URL I got is in the form < jenkins-url >/bitbucket-server-webhook/trigger
3. The pipeline

According to my experience, the creation of the Webhook is demanded to Jenkins, you don't have to do anything on your own other than creating a new Pipeline object. 
Having set the Bitbucket Server Integration configuration up in fact is not enough for the creation of the Webhook, to do that you have to

1. create a new Pipeline
2. flag the Build Trigger "Bitbucket Server trigger build after push"
3. in the Pipeline section, use as Definition "Pipeline Script from SCM" and fill the other fields according to the configuration you have set before.

Point 3 is saying you are retrieving your Pipeline definition from a file stored in Bitbucket itself, you can also customise the name of the file Jenkins is going to look for (by default this should be Jenkinsfile), and use the "Pipeline Syntax" option to get the snippet of code you will use as step in your Jenkinsfile.

Once you have created your Pipeline in Jenkins, the webhook should appear in the right section in your Bitbucket Server repository.